# Populating Textblock From LINQ Query (Web Service)

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml, textblock

I have written a Web Service that allows me to pull information from my SQL DB and display that information in my Universal Windows App. Currently I am displaying this information in a listbox. I would like to display this information in 3 separate textblocks and I am unsure of how to achieve that... This is currently what I have that works fine, but is placing it in a listbox:

**Web Service**

```
 [OperationContract]
 List<TBL_My_Info> FindInfo(string uid);

 public List<TBL_My_Info> FindInfo(string uid)
 {
    DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var res = from r in context.TBL_My_Info where r.User_Name == uid select r;
    return res.ToList();
 }
```

**XAML**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListBox Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
     Margin="8,47,0,0" 
     Name="listBoxInfo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="440">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

**Universal Web Application**

```
private void btnView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string s = txtNameFind.Text;
    this.Content = new Page1(s);
}       

 public Page1(string s)
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    LoadData(s);          
}

private async void LoadData(string s)
{
    var client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    var res = await client.FindMyInfoAsync(s);
    listBoxInfo.ItemsSource = res;
}
```

Basically what I am asking, is how can I get it to the 3 pieces of information to display in 3 separate textblocks, rather than in a listbox...

Thanks

Comment: Try listBoxInfo.DataContext = res;  But really you should consider Binding methodology instead.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the binding methodology, I am open to any suggestions. Not sold on any certain way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of using Binding:

```
//this is the backing store property
public static readonly DependencyProperty ListBoxInfoProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ListBoxInfo", typeOf(ObservableCollection<Tbl_my_Info>), typeof(thisControlType));

//this is the CLR Wrapper
public ObservableCollection<Tbl_my_Info> ListBoxInfo {

    get{return (ObservableCollection<Tbl_my_Info>)GetValue(ListBoxInfoProperty);}
    set{SetValue(ListBoxInfoProperty,value);}
```

In the Window or UserControl after InitializeComponent() call, enter this...

```
DataContext = this;
```

You've just made it possible for XAML to bind to this code.

Now in XAML...

```
<ListBox Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
 Margin="8,47,0,0" 
 ItemsSource = "{Binding ListBoxInfo}"
 Name="listBoxInfo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="440">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Give that a shot....